# How to call a method from Form2 in Form 1

Tags: c#, forms, location

I have a method in Form 2

```
public void set_location(int lx, int ly)
    {
        this.Location = new Point(lx, ly);
    }
```

Which need to be called from Form1, when this event happens

```
 private void Form1_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loc_x = this.Location.X;
        loc_y = this.Location.Y;

    }
```

I Initialize Form2 as a new thread

```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Thread newThread = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate { Application.Run(new Form2()); });
        newThread.Start(); 
    }
```

How do i call method set_location(x,y); from Form1 ?

Comment: I was with you till you said you load form2 as a new thread... why?

Comment: I need both forms visible at the same time. There is a better way of keeping them both active together?

Comment: What do you mean by "active"? Unless you close or hide them, both will be visible. But only one form can have focus at any given time.

Comment: what i want to do is, Form1 loads with something in it and Form 2 Spawns on top of it with a transparency. so Form1 is visible and form2 is visible on top of form1 as a transparent form to draw on its panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there isn't any benefit by the second thread.

The easiest way would be to pass a reference to your form1 in form2's constructor

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    Form2 form2 =new Form2();
    form2.Show(this);
}


private Form1 Parent {get;set;}
public Form2(Form1 form)
{
    this.Parent = form;
}
```

Then you can reference its properties as normal

```
this.Parent.Form1_LocationChanged(this, null);
```

---

In response to your comment, maintain a reference to Form2 in your form1 also and then just call that

```
private void Form1_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    this.form2.set_location(loc_x, loc_y);
}
```

Comment: how do i set Form2's Location from

    this.Parent.Form1_LocationChanged(this, null);

can't i call a method in Form1 to do change Form2's location?

Comment: i decalred 
**public Form2 form2;** before 
**Form1_load** 
**this.form2** inside, _Form1_ **_LocationChanged** gives nullReference.

Comment: Declare it in the constructor (`Form2 form2 = new Form2()`) then show it in the load event.

Comment: @user2967920 - No worries.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void set_location(int lx, int ly)
{
    this.Location = new Point(lx, ly);
}
```

please tell me if this work

Comment: Edit didn't see the static, and its a bad idea, it won't work because there is no `this`

Comment: This will not even compile! There is no `this` in `static` methods.

Comment: I tried doing that. This is what i get "Error 1 Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer"

Comment: @Sayse sorry but maybe i miss understand your question can you rexplain it to me

Comment: Your code won't compile, `this` relates to an instance of the class, since the method is static, it has no instance

Comment: @Sayse then he can iniltiaze an instance of the class then call the method right?

Comment: No, because static methods are not linked to an instance of a class

Answer (score 0):

> Program.cs

```
static class Program
    {
        public static Form GlobalMainForm;

        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            GlobalMainForm = new Form1();
            Application.Run(GlobalMainForm);
        }
    }
```

> Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form2 Form2GlobalInstance { get; set; }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Form2GlobalInstance = new Form2();
            Thread newThread = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate { Application.Run(Form2GlobalInstance); });
            newThread.Start();
            Load += delegate
            {
                var frm2Location = Form2GlobalInstance.GetLocation();
                MessageBox.Show("location.x=" + frm2Location.X + " location.y=" + frm2Location.Y);
            };
        }

    }
```

> Form2.cs

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Point GetLocation()
    {
        return new Point(Location.X, Location.Y);
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("location.x=" + Program.GlobalMainForm.Location.X + " location.y=" + Program.GlobalMainForm.Location.Y);
    }
}
```

> Update 1:

```
static class Program
{
    public static Form MainForm;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        MainForm = new Form1();
        Application.Run(MainForm);
    }
}
```

**From2:**

```
public void Form1_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        loc_x =Program.MainForm.Location.X;
        loc_y = Program.MainForm.Location.Y;    
}
```

OR
Ways to run a method in a new Thread
[LINK](http://kenegozi.com/blog/2006/08/10/ways-to-run-a-method-in-a-new-thread)

Comment: You made `Form1_LocationChanged` private so this doesn't compile

Comment: This will not compile. You cannot call a non-static method on a class name. You need an instance.

Comment: @nvoigt - Hamix made an instance, with the same name as the class (another reason it wont compile)

Comment: Have you tried using a MethodInvoker to perform the call? This allows for making cross-thread operations.

Comment: Also: Form2 =new Form2(); is obviously missing instance name.